# What's with Ruby's ZipInputStream screwing up my line endings?

Tags: ruby, zip, newline, zipinputstream

I'd be happy with ZipInputStream taking indecent liberties with the line endings that are stored in a file if it would at least get them right for the platform I'm storing the file on.  Unfortunately, I pull a text file (.txt, .cpp. .etc.) out of a zip and the \n (0x0A) gets replaced with a \r\n (0x0d0a) and, as you can imagine, this is causing me a great deal of trouble.

Is there a flag I can set to tell it either to avoid changing the line endings altogether or to use one of my choosing?

Thanks.

(I've checked the zip file, my creation of it, etc.  I've extracted it using other zip tools and verified that it is archived properly.  I've stepped through my project with rdebug and seen that the ZipInputStream call to read() is returning \r\n for line endings.)

Answer (score 0):

if you have an `open(filename)` or `open(filename,"r")` call in your code, try to replace it with `open(filename,"rb")`